# how to declare a formGroup in angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  signupForm: FormGroup | undefined;
  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    
   }
 


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username:[' ', Validators.required],
      email:[' ', Validators.required],
      password:[' ',[Validators.required]]
    })
  }
}
```

**and the following bug:**

src/app/auth/signup/signup.component.ts:6:16
6   templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component SignupComponent.

Error: src/app/auth/signup/signup.component.html:40:110 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

40                                 <span *ngIf="!signupForm.get('password').valid && signupForm.get('password').touched">
~~~~~~~

src/app/auth/signup/signup.component.ts:6:16
6   templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component SignupComponent.

Error: src/app/auth/signup/signup.component.ts:10:3 - error TS2564: Property 'signupForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to remove `| undefined` or your span should look like below (null protected)

```
<span *ngIf="!signupForm?.get('password')?.valid && signupForm?.get('password')?.touched">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors here.

#### First Error

This error is happening because of where you put your form builder code. You should move it out of the ngOnInit method, and put it at the top of your declaration. This would end up looking like this:

```
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
 signupForm =  this.formBuilder.group({
    username:[' ', Validators.required],
    email:[' ', Validators.required],
    password:[' ',[Validators.required]]
  })
}
 constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

 }



ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

the ngOnInit lifecycle method gets called after the component is created by the constructor, but before it gets rendered, or any other lifecycle methods get called. This means that anything you set in here will be null or undefined for a little bit until Angular calls this method.

This means that for this brief period, the code in your template is calling a method on an undefined or null object, which gives you this error. If you move the builder out of ngOnInit, then the component never exists without a complete form object, since creating it is part of the creation process for the component itself.

#### Second Error

The second error is happening because you're missing a '?' on your method calls after your 'get' calls. The '.get' method might return a null value if the field doesn't exist. So if you try to access a method on the result of the .get method like you are in your template, you need to add a '?' to signal that the object being called might not exist.